# what does the "e" modifier to the s/// command mean in GNU sed?

Tags: sed

I have read [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) manual for the `s///` command. There it says:

> `e`
>
> This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into pattern
>       space.   If a substitution was made, the command that is found in
>       pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced with its output.
>       A trailing newline is suppressed; results are undefined if the command
>       to be executed contains a nul character. This is a GNU sed extension.

I don't know what is useful:

```
echo "1234" | sed 's/1/echo ss/e'
echo "1234" | sed 's/1/ss/'
```

These two commands result in the same, so what is the `e` modifier about?

Comment: I suggest to replace  `/echo` by `/touch` and take a look at `ls -ltr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ printf "%s\n" 1234 2345 3456 |
> sed -e 's/\(..\)\(..\)/echo $((\1 * \2))/e'
408
1035
1904
$
```

This `printf` command echoes three 4-digit numbers on three lines. The `sed` script splits each line into a pair of 2-digit numbers, creates a command `echo $((12 * 34))`, for example, runs it, and the output (408 for the given values) is included in (as) the pattern space — which is then printed.  So, for this script, the pairs of 2-digit numbers are multiplied and the result is shown.

You can get fancier if you wish:

```
$ printf "%s\n" 1234 2345 3456 |
> sed -e 's/\(..\)\(..\)/echo \1 \\* \2 = $((\1 * \2))/e'
12 * 34 = 408
23 * 45 = 1035
34 * 56 = 1904
$
```

Note the double backslash — that's rather important.  You could avoid the need for that using double quotes:

```
printf "%s\n" 1234 2345 3456 |
sed -e 's/\(..\)\(..\)/echo "\1 * \2 = $((\1 * \2))"/e'
```

Beware: the notation will run the external command every time the `s///` command actually makes a substitution.  If you have millions of lines of data in your files, that could mean millions of commands executed.

Answer (score 2):

The `/e` option is a GNU `sed` extension.  It causes the result of the replacement to be passed to the shell for evaluation as a command.  Observe:

```
vnix$ sed 's/a/pwd/' <<<a
pwd

vnix$ sed 's/a/pwd/e' <<<a
/home/tripleee
```

Your example caused identical behavior (echoing back exactly the replaced text) so it was a poorly chosen example.

Out of the box, the *pattern space* refers to the current input line, but there are ways to put something else in the pattern space.  Substitution modifies the pattern space, but there are other `sed` commands which modify the pattern space in other ways. (For a trivial example, `x` swaps the pattern space with the *hold space,* which is basically another built-in variable which you can use for whatever you want.)